# Dexguard skipping jni libs in release apk

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, dexguard

I am implementing **dexguard** in my project, but generated app is crashing and giving following error:

**Caused by:**

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.gemalto.android.root.internal.MedlJni.goMedlJni:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;) at com.gemalto.android.root.internal.MedlJni.goMedlJni(Native Method)

I unzipped the generated apk also and found that libs folder is missing in that. What rules should be applied to dexguard file to prevent dexguard from eliminating libs in release apk?

Please suggest the ways to rectify the **error**.

Comment: while runnning dexguard i am getting this warning "Warning: Can't read elf file 'lib/arm64-v8a/libmedl.so', will be copied unprocessed: Invalid ELF format: wrong magic bytes [lib/arm64-v8a/libmedl.so]

Answer (score 1):

To keep the native library files use:

```
-keepresourcefiles lib/**.so
```

Comment: ya i got this solution to keep the lib files but still the warning message persist.

Comment: It is difficult to investigate such an issue via stackoverflow. I would suggest that you forward your problem to support@guardsquare.com for further investigation.